# Flagged to get obsolete question deleted, flag rejected - What would have been a better way?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I flagged this since the asker could not be bothered to delete it after having found the mistake in a completely different place.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368347/showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list-in-console-log

My flag:

> Please delete. User found the missing bracket elsewhere

It was declined - *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*

So what are my options if a flag is not the way?

*Delete* is not an option available on this question for some reason

**Update** seems this discussion bore fruit. Question was deleted before I could accept the answer to this question

Comment: Ehhm, don't you have delete vote powers? Is that really an issue to flag moderadors busy on more important stuff?

Comment: Yes but not available for this question. - I see "protect" which is even more weird. Had I been moderator I would not find it a waste of time to delete this

Comment: Moderators don't care about question quality. That's "up to the community to decide", regardless of its ability to action. You're out of luck if you want a site without awful questions because on this one there are zero people with the ability to remove them.

Comment: @mplungjan  _"Yes but not available for this question. ..."_ So just wait for more downvotes coming, and if there are enough and the question was closed, delete vote.

Comment: @bjb568 I am not questioning the QUALITY of the question. That is moot since the question was never valid to begin with. The question is useless to anyone regardless of quality since it was a local problem found somewhere else than the code posted. Anyway, bedtime here.

Comment: Why can't you close it - *The error in this question was caused by a typographical error*? Then just let the automatic deletion system kick in whenever it needs to?

Comment: @mplungjan Eh, I'm using quality in a general sense. If it's not useful, it's not high-quality.

Comment: If you're not sure if a flag is warranted you can always drop in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room that has enough regulars around that can judge the validity of such flags and/or provide alternative moderation options.

Comment: [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flagging for a moderator to delete a question is almost always a waste of their time. They don't need to be brought in on every case. They're exception handlers, and should only be called in when exceptions occur. Deletion of a random question which has been closed simply because your delete option hasn't appeared yet isn't an exception. Imagine if every one of these got flagged - the moderators would be even more overwhelmed with flags than they already are.

**Better options:**

- Downvote the question. Once the question reaches a score of -3, users with over 20k (like you) reputation can begin voting to delete it immediately. Otherwise, they have to wait for 48 hours to pass after closure, along with the 10k reputation users.
- Ignore it. Seriously. The system will automatically delete this question after 9 days with absolutely no effort needed from the community whatsoever. For reference, the specific deletion criteria I'm referring to is:

  - Closed more than 9 days ago
  - Not closed as a duplicate
  - Score <= 0
  - Not locked
  - No answers with a score > 0
  - No accepted answer
  - No pending reopen votes
  - No edits in the past 9 days

  Assuming the asker doesn't come back and keep editing it, the problem will go away on its own.
- Wait the 48 hours. I guess if you really want to make sure the question gets deleted and have the time to look at it again later.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.